# MATLAB: Array of structure initialization in CLASS properties

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, struct

I would like to create a file which will store properties containing desired values.
Each property has to be defined as an array of struct.
My current way of array of struct initialization:

```
classdef myClass < handle

    properties(Constant)
          myProp1  = struct(...
                     'Name', {'A','B'},...
                     'Value', {'1','2'});
    end

end
```

How I wish to write my array of struct(which I feel is more clean and readable):

```
classdef myClass < handle

    properties(Constant)
          myProp1(1).Name = 'A';
          myProp1(1).Value = 1;

          myProp1(2).Name = 'B';
          myProp1(2).Value = 2;
    end

end
```

How should I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: Am I correct that you get following error when creating an object of type myClass:
`Error using myClass |
Error: File: myClass.m Line: 5 Column: 18 | 
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.`

With my Matlab R2011b I can't create structs with the dot-syntax in the properties, e.g. `myProp.Name = 'A'` leads to the same syntax error. Probably the dot is confused with object access.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to create structures in the properties definition like you proposed. (See my comment on your question). An alternative is to create the array of structs in the constructor. Use `(SetAccess=private)`, so that the properties may not be changed from outside.

```
% myClass.m
classdef myClass < handle
    properties(SetAccess=private)
        myProp1 = struct
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass() % constructor
            obj.myProp1(1).Name = 'A';
            obj.myProp1(1).Value = 1;
            obj.myProp1(2).Name = 'B';
            obj.myProp1(2).Value = 2;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

It seems that the property `myProp` in `myClass` represents something else. For sake of simplicity I will assume it is a person (you will need to adapt the example to cover your needs). You can create a `Person` class with properties `Name`, `Value`, `ParentName` and use it in your class. The property section in `myClass` would look like this:

```
myProp(1) = Person(name1, value1, parent_name1);
myProp(2) = Person(name2, value2, parent_name2);
...
myProp(N) = Person(nameN, valueN, parent_nameN);
```

Alternatively you can prepare your `Person` class to accept arrays as inputs:

```
names        = {name1,  name2,  ..., nameN};
values       = [value1, value2, ..., valueN];
parent_names = {pname1, pname2, ..., pnameN};

... %//possibly more code here

myProp = Person(names, values, parent_names);
```

and the class `Person` would take care of always keep them in the right order, provide setters and getters, etc.

A stub of a `Person` class for the first solution would look like this (a class accepting arrays would be longer):

```
classdef Person < handle
    properties (Access = private)
        name        = '';
        value       = 0;
        parent_name = '';
    end
    methods (Access = public)
        function this = Person(name, value, parent_name)
            this.SetName(name);
            this.SetValue(value);
            this.SetParentName(parent_name);
        end
        function SetName(this, name)
            this.name = name;
        end
        function SetValue(this, value)
            this.value = value;
        end
        function SetParentName(this, parent_name)
            this.parent_name = parent_name;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried the above method of having a Person class, but as soon as I define the property myProp(1) in myClass properties,  I get an error saying " Parse error at '(' : Usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: @Spooferman it is difficult to know without looking at the code. Most likely you are making a syntax mistake. These mistakes are marked in red by the mlint. What I described above was only one idea (object composition) to solve a problem, but you must adapt your code to your needs.

Comment: In my eyes it would be more elegant to implement the object with arrays of property-objects like @gire said (aggregation).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your original way of setting up `myProp`.

But if you're concerned just about readability, you could add a private static method called something like `makeMyProp`, which can be laid out as attractively as you want, which returns a filled out structure `myProp`.

Then, in the `properties` section, say `myProp = myClass.makeMyProp;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
classdef myClass < handle

    properties(Constant)
          myProp1a = struct('Name','A','Value',1);
          myProp1b = struct('Name','B','Value',2);
          myProp1 = [myClass.myProp1a, myClass.myProp1b];
    end

end
```

Comment: [An explanation along with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) helps understand the answer more clearly.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`enumeration`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html)(yes, this apparently exists in MATLAB).

An example usage would be:

```
classdef ExampleEnum < uint8 %// Can also be another datatype
    enumeration
    %//  name  value
          A     (1)
          B     (2)
    end    
end
```

Then MATLAB automatically uses the string or the value depending on how you use your enum object (this is mentioned in the documentation).

Comment: This actually does not address my issue. The second field( in my example above) could be a string too. Also, we can have multiple fields. Like Name, Value, ParentName, etc